# Can you exact the full Schema From Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, schema, extract, information-schema

I want to pull the whole schema for a Big Query Table including the Description that was entered

I have been using this

SELECT
 * 
FROM
 `wtr-digital-analytics`.Order_Fulfilment_Current.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

But it does not show the Description , it must be stored somewhere .

[Table Schema image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfO0e.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use the **TABLE_OPTIONS** view to get the description.

**Example:**

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS
```

**Reference:**

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#table_options_view

Comment: @Phil if this solves your problem, accept as a answer.